# Openmp fortran, task dependency on overlapping subarrays

Tags: fortran, openmp

**TLDR: task parallel code fails to recognize task dependency on partially overlapping subarrays**

I'm trying to parallelize some fortran code using task parallelism. I'm struggling to get the task dependency to work.

The following minimal example illustrates my problem:

```
program test

   integer, parameter :: n = 100
   double precision :: A(n,n),B(n,n)
   integer :: istart, istop

   !$omp parallel
   !$omp single

   istart = 20
   istop = 50

   !$omp task shared(A,B) firstprivate(istart,istop)&
   !$omp& depend( in: B(istart:istop,istart:istop) )&
   !$omp& depend( inout: A(istart:istop,istart:istop) )
   write(*,*) "starting task 1"
   call sleep(5)
   write(*,*) "stopping task 1"
   !$omp end task

   istart = 30
   istop = 60

   !$omp task shared(A,B) firstprivate(istart,istop)&
   !$omp& depend( in: B(istart:istop,istart:istop) )&
   !$omp& depend( inout: A(istart:istop,istart:istop) )
   write(*,*) "starting task 2"
   call sleep(5)
   write(*,*) "stopping task 2"
   !$omp end task

   !$omp end single nowait
   !$omp end parallel

end program
```

Which I compile using gcc version 9.4.0 and the `-fopenmp` flag.

The code has two tasks. Task 1 depends on `A(20:50,20:50)` and task 2 depends on `A(30:60,30:60)`. These subarrays overlap, so I would expect task 2 to wait until task 1 has completed, but the output I get is:

```
 starting task 1
 starting task 2
 stopping task 1
 stopping task 2
```

If I comment out the lines

```
istart = 30
istop = 60
```

so that the subarrays are exactly the same instead of just overlapping, task 2 does wait on task 1.

Are task dependencies with overlapping subarrays not supported in openmp? Or am I defining the dependencies wrong somehow?

Comment: Reading the standard, array sections are allowed there. But you may be asking a bit much of the compiler. Can you try a different compiler?

Comment: More recent version of gfortran (12.2) result in the same output. I don't have access to ifort right now.

Comment: After some more digging, I think the openmp standard disallows it. "List items used in depend clauses of the same task or sibling tasks must indicate identical storage locations or disjoint storage locations." Overlapping arrays do not have disjoint storage locations.

Comment: That would settle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> These subarrays overlap

This is forbidden by the OpenMP standard as pointed out by @ThijsSteel.

This choice has been done because of the resulting runtime overhead. Indeed, checking overlapping regions of array in dependencies was very expensive in pathological cases (especially for arrays with many dimensions). A typical example of pathological case when many tasks write on the same array (but on different exclusive parts) and then one tasks operate on the whole array. This create a lot of checks and dependencies while this can be optimized using a specific dependency pattern. An even more pathological case is a transposition of the sub-arrays (from `n` horizontal bands to `n` vertical bands): this quickly results in `n²` dependencies which is insanely inefficient when `n` is large. An optimization consists in aggregating the dependencies so to get `2*n` dependencies but this is expensive to do at runtime and a better way would actually not to use dependency but task group synchronization.

From the user point-of-view, there are only few options:

- operate at bigger grain even though it means having more synchronization (so possibly poor performance);
- try to regroup tasks operating on distinct sub-array by checking that manually. You can cheat OpenMP by using fake dependencies so to do that or add more tasks synchronizations (typically a `taskwait`). You can also make use of advanced task-dependence-type modifiers like `depobj`, `inoutset`
  or `mutexinoutset` now available in recent version of the OpenMP standard.

Most of the time, an algorithm is typically composed of a several waves of tasks and each wave is operating on non-overlapping sub-arrays. In this case, you can just add a task synchronization at the end of the computation (or use recursive tasks).

This is a known limitation of OpenMP and some researchers worked on it (including me). I expect new specific dependency modifiers to be added in the future, and possibly user-defined partitioning-related features in the long run (some research runtimes like StarPU does that for example, but not everyone agree adding that in OpenMP as this is a bit high-level and not simple to include).

Comment: In what sort of application would this be of use? I can image coding an LU factorization that way, but multi-threaded BLAS already exists, and is way more efficient than an OMP solution would be.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I am confused. What do you means by "this"? The dependency over overlapping sub-arrays or the use of partitioning methods?

Comment: I thought you were talking about overlapping sub-arrays that you were working on & adding in the future. But feel free to answer more general: what is the use case for more dependency modifiers.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I'm applying this in two sided factorisations (specifically Hessenberg-triangular reduction). Those often have some moving windows that may overlap.

Comment: Also fun note, an LU using multi-threaded blas works as follows: LU of subblock (not parallel), triangular multiplication of 2 panels (slightly parallel), update of trailing submatrix (very parallel). An OMP solution can already calculate the LU of the subblock while some of the trailing submatrix is still being updated. But maybe you were talking about multi-threaded LAPACK implementations like MKL, which does do this kind of parallel implementation for as far as i know.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I think one missing modifier is one that can cross the task region boundary. Basically, the idea is to define dependency on tasks which are non-sibling ones (like children of a task which is a sibling tasks of the parent task of the current generated one). The typical use case for this is to define fine-grain dependencies between two set of recursive tasks (eg. for AMR-based application). The typical solution to do that is to flatten the task graph but this is not always easy nor possible (without performance issues, especially prior to OpenMP 5.1).

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Just to give some additional context. I worked on the software composition of HPC task-based code (ie. how design HPC applications using building-blocks of code, with well-defined interface, making use of fine-grained tasks). In this context, several algorithmic steps (eg. EP, Stencil, LU, FFT) of an application can operate on different partitions. A partition with overlapping is quite rare in HPC (beside for ghosts), but since sibling tasks of different algorithmic steps can operate on different partition which can overlap each other, the OpenMP constraint was an issue.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout The inoutset modifier of OpenMP 5.1 help a lot to do some kind of repartitioning so for the algorithmic building blocks to be relatively independent, but doing that efficiently manually is far from being easy for end-users (which end up doing some over-synchronizations). Besides, mixing codes making uses of recursive tasks and ones using non-recursive tasks without inefficient over-synchronizations is still an issue in OpenMP 5.1 (this is not a frequent use-case but it typically happens in large complex HPC applications mixing a lot of various algorithmic steps).

Comment: AFAIK, LU decomposition is done in LAPACK libraries (or related ones) and not BLAS. Some LAPACK libraries use OpenMP internally and especially tasks. [PLASMA](https://icl.utk.edu/files/print/2017/plasma-sc17.pdf) does that for example (AFAIK they moved away from their own dataflow tasking system implemented in QUARK initially). DAG of tasks are pretty useful for QR/LU/Cholesky decomposition to express the complex dependencies between tiles and also because a non-trivial scheduling is generally needed to be fast (one need to take care of the critical path, not to mention accelerators).

Comment: @JérômeRichard (you're giving me a lot to digest) "partition with overlapping" Ghost regions are overlapping but they don't have concurrent writes. Additive Schwarz methods do overlap, and they have concurrent writes.